# List becomes String when Marshalling object to json

Tags: json, jaxb, marshalling

I'm getting a pretty strange error when marshalling my object to json. My object is annotated like this.

My class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "myobject")
public class MyObject {

private List<String> contactPersonsForMyObject;

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement()
public List<String> getContactPersonsForMyObject() {
    return contactPersonsForMyObject;
}

public void setContactPersonsForMyObject(List<String> contactPersonsForMyObject) {
    this.contactPersonsForMyObject = contactPersonsForMyObject;
   } 
}
```

Everything works fine except for that if the List contactPersonsForMyObject contains only one value it get's marshalled to a string which ofcourse creates problems since the application consuming this expects a list.

The marshalled object:

```
[
        {
            "myobject": {
                "somethingcool": "amazing",
                "contactPersonsForMyObject": [
                    "test.test@gmail.com",
                    "test@test.se"
                ],
                "myObjectId": "c85e48730501bfae41e67714c6131b7d"
            }
        },
        {
            "myobject": {
                "somethingcool": "cool",
                "contactPersonsForMyObject":"test@test2.se",                
                "myObjectId": "c85e48730501bfae41e67714cqwerty"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Why does this happen and how do I force it to create a list with one value?

Comment: Are you using any other libraries other than the JAXB ones?

Comment: Yes, jboss-seam-resteasy 1.2.1.GA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Jackson to handle processing your objects into JSON, it solved the same array problem for me in the past. If you are using RESTEasy (version 1.2 GA) with Maven, [this link should help you get things setup](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html/json.html) to use Jackson to serialize objects to JSON.

[This article](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/) also has some useful information for integrating Jackson with RESTEasy. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I had to move this issue back in the backlog, but I will try it out next sprint! Stay tuned!

Comment: Yup! That did the trick, i removed the annotations for JAXB and instead of using Jettision(Default) to marshall the objects I implemented resteasy-jackson-provider according to your recommended site. Thank you!